# Proofing an identity for free variable

Tags: proof-explanation, solution-verification, problem-solving

Let us suppose we have a function such that

$$z = e^{1/ab} - 1$$

Where we have two free parameters, a and b.

**Q1**) Can we say that as $b \rightarrow \infty$, $z = 0$?

Or, since $a$ is a free parameter, there is always some value for $a$ such that $z \neq 0$ for  $b \rightarrow \infty$ ?

Comment: Making $b\to \infty$ has little effect on the product $ab,$ since (as you note) $a$ is free to be some function of $b.$

Comment: What you **can** say is that for **any fixed non-zero** value of $a$ (positive or negative), as $b \to \infty, ~z \to 0.$

Comment: @user2661923 thats not what I am looking for

Comment: Agreed.  But for what you are looking for, the comment of coffeemath pertains.

Comment: @user2661923 is it also valid for both cases, as I have explained above ? If thats the case, how can you proof it ?

Comment: "Is there a difference between these two situations ? In this case for $b = \infty$ and $b \to \infty$".  Yes: $b = \infty$ is **nonsensical** since $\infty$ is not a number but rather a symbol for unbounded growth.  Focusing on the $b \to \infty$ issue, consider the following three sub-cases: $a = \frac{1}{b}$, $a = \frac{1}{\sqrt{b}}$, and $a = \frac{1}{b^2}$.

Comment: @user2661923 my mistake. So there is always some a value..